# PIG LATIN script error 1000

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig

I have created the following script wherein I am trying to use the piggybank UDF:

```
register /home/hduser/pig/contrib/piggybank/java/piggybank.jar;
divs = load 'NYSE_dividends.txt' using PigStorage(',') as (exchange:chararray, symbol:chararray, date:chararray, dividends:float);
backwards = foreach divs generate 
org.apache.pig.piggybank.evaluation.string.Reverse(symbol);
store backwards into '/user/hduser/backwards.csv';
```

When I run the above line by line in GRUNT shell it works fine however, when I try to run it as a script the following error comes up:

```
2014-03-10 22:42:25,375 [main] ERROR org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.Grunt - ERROR 1000: Error during parsing. File not found: /user/hduser/register.pig
```

I am using HADOOP 1.2.1 and PIG 0.12 in pseudocluster mode.

The log is below:

```
Pig Stack Trace
---------------
ERROR 1000: Error during parsing. File not found: register.pig

org.apache.pig.tools.pigscript.parser.ParseException: File not found: register.pig
    at org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.GruntParser.loadScript(GruntParser.java:547)
    at org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.GruntParser.processScript(GruntParser.java:509)
    at org.apache.pig.tools.pigscript.parser.PigScriptParser.Script(PigScriptParser.java:1014)
    at org.apache.pig.tools.pigscript.parser.PigScriptParser.parse(PigScriptParser.java:550)
    at org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.GruntParser.parseStopOnError(GruntParser.java:198)
    at org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.GruntParser.parseStopOnError(GruntParser.java:173)
    at org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.Grunt.run(Grunt.java:69)
    at org.apache.pig.Main.run(Main.java:541)
    at org.apache.pig.Main.main(Main.java:156)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:160)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're using the example from "Programming Pig" (Author Alan Gates, 2011, O'Reilly Media), which has a program called "register.pig".  One piece of information you're not showing here is how you've executed the command, so I'm guessing that you ran:

```
pig -f /user/hduser/register.pig
```

This path looks like it's referencing HDFS, but the file should be on your local filesystem,  so you should try

`pig -f /local/path/register.pig`

Note:  You can also register UDFs on the command line when executing your script, too.  This way you don't have to register it inside the script, if you prefer not to.

`pig -f /local/path/register.pig -Dpig.additional.jars=/home/hduser/pig/contrib/piggybank/java/piggybank.jar`

Comment: Yes, you are right I am taking this example from the book. All the files are on my HDFS system however, I will try it in local mode as well.

Comment: You can make sure it's using the MapReduce engine when executing the script by using the "-x mapreduce" option for pig.

Comment: Resolved there were some silly mistakes in the script which I was not able to locate now corrected and working fine now. I have to be more careful.